# WIM: Variant Type for uint32?

Tags: winapi, com

The definition of a WIM/CIM method takes an input parameter "uint32".

I used `InitVariantFromUInt32()` to setup the variable that is used but `IWbemClassObject::put()` complains that `WBEM_E_TYPE_MISMATCH (0x80041005)`

What would a `uint32` VARIANT type supposed to be?

TIA!!

Comment: Use `InitVariantFromInt32` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/numbers

| Data type | Automation type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sint8 | VT_I2 | Signed 8-bit integer. |
| sint16 | VT_I2 | Signed 16-bit integer. |
| sint32 | VT_I4 | Signed 32-bit integer. |
| sint64 | VT_BSTR | Signed 64-bit integer in string form. This type follows hexadecimal or decimal format according to the American National Standards Institute (ANSI) C rules. |
| real32 | VT_R4 | 4-byte floating-point value that follows the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers, Inc. (IEEE) standard. |
| real64 | VT_R8 | 8-byte floating-point value that follows the IEEE standard. |
| uint8 | VT_UI1 | Unsigned 8-bit integer. |
| uint16 | VT_I4 | Unsigned 16-bit integer. |
| uint32 | VT_I4 | Unsigned 32-bit integer. |
| uint64 | VT_BSTR | Unsigned 64-bit integer in string form. This type follows hexadecimal or decimal format according to ANSI C rules. |